# Is it possible to factor $27$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt7]$ other than in $27=3\cdot3\cdot 3$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I need to know if there exists an element of norm$27$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 7]$, that is, whether there are any integer solutions to $a^2 - 7b^2 = 27$. When I used modular arithmetic, I find out that $a^2 \equiv b^2$ (mod 3). Now I'm not exactly sure what this is supposed to tell me.

Edit: I just found out that $27 = -(2 + \sqrt(7))^3 (2 - \sqrt(7))^3$ so how can we just say that 27 doesn't factor?

Comment: Could you edit the title to make your question clearer?

Comment: @NavyColors please see my response for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the only squares mod $7$ are $1,2,4$.  This means that $a^2 \not\equiv 6 \equiv 27 \pmod{7}$ for any $a$, so the desired equation is impossible.

Comment: But wait a second! I just got this crazy factorization of 27: $-(2 + \sqrt(7))^3 (2 - \sqrt(7))^3$ I'll edit that in my main post.

Comment: @NavyColors This shows that $27$ can be factored even when $a^2-7b^2 = 27$ is impossible, since $a^2 - 7b^2 = -27$ is possible.

Comment: I see. Your response showed me that $N(a + b\sqrt(n))$ must be considered in the negative case. I had no idea that such a rule applied.

Answer (score 1):

Your question about factoring and solutions to the equation $a^2-7b^2=27$ are NOT exactly the same question.

Suppose we can factor $27 =\alpha \beta$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$. Then the norms will behave as follows:
\begin{align*}
27^2 & = N(\alpha) N(\beta)\\
& = (a^2-7b^2)(c^2-7d^2).
\end{align*}
So in order to show that $27=3^3$ is the only factorization you will need to rule out other possibilities, of which $a^2-7b^2=27$ is one.

**For the equation $a^2-7b^2=27$:**

Suppose $a^2-7b^2=27$ has integer solutions. Then 
$$a^2 +b^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{8}.$$
But $a^2 \equiv 0,1,4 \pmod{8}$ and same for $b^2$. Thus $a^2+b^2 \not\equiv 3 \pmod{8}$. Hence no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$a^2-7b^2=27$ implies $a^2\equiv -1\pmod 7$, so there is no solution.